# How print Cyrillic text in code blocks console

Tags: c++, console, codeblocks, cyrillic

I use code blocks 17.12, C++ 98 version on windows 7 Ultimate and I need to print Cyrillic text in the console.

Can you help me :)

```
#include<iostream>
#include <locale>    
using namespace std;
int main(){
long long r[5],turseno,brNamereni=0,ir,ic;
cout<<"Напиши 5 числа.После въдеди още едно"<<"\n"<<"Програмата ще ти 
изведе колко пъти"<<"\n"<<"се среща написанато число по-горе";
//This is bulgarian language.
for(ic=0;ic<5;ic++){
cin>>r[ic];
}

cin>>turseno;
for(ir=0;ir<5;ir++){
if(turseno==r[ir]){
brNamereni++;
}
}
cout<<brNamereni;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you put `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Bulgarian");` at the beginning of main() ?

Comment: It is working.Thank you. :)
Write it as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the locale information of your program to Bulgarian by putting `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Bulgarian");` at the beginning of `main()`. The locale settings determine how language-specific input/output operations are handled.

Comment: Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
int a[2]={1,2};
int b,d;
for(int i=0;i<2;++i)
{
cin>>b; 
    }
int c;
cin>>c;
for(int j=0;j<2;++j)
{`enter code here`
if(a[j]==c)
d++;    
        }
cout<<"enter number u wanna check";     
cout<<d;                
}
```